# What are some ways that I can be self-deprecating about my Chinese speaking ability?

Tags: word-choice, phrase

I live in an area where there are many Chinese so I get plenty of opportunity to use my language skills including shopping, eating at restaurants and meeting new people.

The Chinese people I meet are always complimentary about my language skill although I think it is quite average.

What are some different ways I can express to people that I feel my skill level is not very good?

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of expressing that?

Comment: @NS.X. Self-deprecating when someone compliments you on something is a proper Chinese way to show politeness.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following sentences which demonstrate humility:

- 不好意思，我的中文水平尚浅，有待跟您多多学习。
  Sorry, my Chinese language skill is still shallow, there is still a lot to learn from you.
- 我的中文只不过马马虎虎而已，请您多多包涵。
  My Chinese is just so-so only, please bear with me.
- 我的中文说得不好，请别见怪。
  I am not good at speaking Mandarin, hope you don't mind.

If someone is praising your language ability, you can express in the following manners immediately after the compliments:

- 哪里，哪里... (Nah, you think too highly of me...)
- 您过奖了。 (You flatter me.)

Comment: I noticed a small error, 包含 should be 包涵. 包含 is actually "include, contain".

Comment: These seem rather formal to me.

Comment: @MikeManilone, I have made the change. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: +1 for the last ones.

Comment: What does 'where got' mean? Never heard of it. Edit: Upon further research, looks like it is Singaporean slang. I'd avoid using it here as it's not understood by anyone outside that area. (I assume you live in Singapore).

Comment: @JamesJiao, I try to follow the Chinese meaning as close as possible. Thanks for pointing out the mistake, hope it's better now :p

Comment: @JamesJiao You're right that "Where got" is weird, but I'd like to point out that `哪里` is quite normal.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Yes. I was only inquiring about the English. Had no problem with the Chinese ;).

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet:

- 没有，没有。 No, no, [it's not so good].

江南 style:

- 我[中文]还讲得一般般。 I still don't speak that great.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you say

> 其实还好啦 (qi shi hai hao la) - It's actually just ok!

It's very casual and easy going. I don't suggest you say something too formal, too humble or too complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

I had an early-intermediate textbook where the character who was learning responded, "还差得远呢".

Be careful that you don't make your self-deprecation too impressive or advanced (at least relative to your actual level), that could send a mixed signal!

Answer (score 0):

You could try as a response:
谢谢可是我仅知道很少汉语
Xièxiè kěshì wǒ jǐn zhīdào hěn shǎo hànyǔ

I always forget which to put at the end but it is something I have use well still learning

But if you answer James question he will probably give you something much better :P

Comment: It's ok, but sounds very awkward to my ears.